# Applying function on vector in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new to programming in R and I am wondering why this does not work:

```
w <- c(1,0)
deriv(~x^2+y,c("x","y"),function.arg = TRUE)(w)
```

I really want to apply the function produced by deriv() on a variable w.
Maybe some background on how to deal with these kinds of "macros" might be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `do.call` and pass the 'w' as a `list` of arguments

```
do.call(deriv(~x^2+y,c("x","y"),function.arg = TRUE), as.list(w))
```

Comment: So it is not possible to apply a function taking two arguments x and y on a vector ```v <- c(x1,y1)``` directly? Just checking to see I´m not missing anything

Comment: @MF14 with `do.call`, it is something like the argument unpacking while converting to a list

Answer (score 0):

Your function exposes two non-default parameters but you only pass one argument. Below would work, if this is your intention:

```
w <- c(1,0)

deriv( ~ x^2 + y, c("x","y"), function.arg = TRUE)(w, w)
# [1] 2 0
# attr(,"gradient")
#      x y
# [1,] 2 1
# [2,] 0 1
```

Alternatively, set up a default parameter:

```
w <- c(1,0)

deriv( ~ x^2 + y, c("x","y"), function.arg = function(x, y=2){})(x=w)

# [1] 3 2
# attr(,"gradient")
#      x y
# [1,] 2 1
# [2,] 0 1

# MORE READABLE VERSION WITH identity()
myfunc <- deriv( ~x^2 + y, c("x","y"), func = function(x, y=2) identity(x,y))
myfunc(x=w)
```